# Using htaccess for pretty URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I want to rewrite (shorten) for example **website.com/contact.html** to **website.com/contact-us**, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It just displays "The page isn't rediercting properly" or "The page cannot be found" or some other fatal error. Note that I'm not looking for a way to hide an extension.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<a href="contact-us">Contact</a>
```

RewriteRule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact-us http://www.website.com/contact.html
```

Basically I'm just trying to figure out how to beautify URLs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You were redirecting the user back to the starting point. You can post the solution as answer or close the question if you think it won't help others.

Comment: Okay, but users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this worked:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact-us contact.html
```